# try catch Unreachable Code Detected

Tags: c#

**Note: Read whole question before downvoting please.**

I have the following code. The code serves as a repro. I want this code to reach the `Console.Read();` cause I want to use this in my project. I want to continue execution after exception handling.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;

namespace Sample
{
  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                throw new FormatException("Format");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex is FormatException || ex is OverflowException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Caught Exception");
                    return;
                }
                throw;
            }

            Console.Read();       //Unreachable Code Detected.
        }
```

I am getting following Warning:

> Warning    1   Unreachable code detected   G:\Samplework\Program.cs    39

- How can I solve this issue?
- I want the code to be reachable.

Comment: You either return when the exception is caught or throw it again. Both of those will end the program.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance I am returning in `if` loop and also `throw'ing after it

Comment: You need to change your control flow so that the code is reachable. There's no generic way to tell you how to do that. At the moment, every path throw that `try`/`catch` block results in control flow leaving `Main`.

Comment: You don't need try-catch block at all. Or you forgot to add something in try-catch, e.g. some validation.

Comment: In what case would you like to make it reach Console.Read()?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I have made this sample from my project. as a repro

Comment: @Donvoters: Comments are acceptable.

Comment: Rather than downvoting the people answering your question, please clarify your question.

Answer (score 2):

you are missing the [finally](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dszsf989%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) part in your try/catch

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            throw new FormatException("Format");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex is FormatException || ex is OverflowException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Caught Exception");
                return;
            }
            throw;
        }
        // add this
        finally
        {
            Console.Read();      
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the Console.Read() will never execute, as the method will either return, or throw an exception.

Comment: I already know that it is not executing. I want to make it reachable. and remove that warning.

Comment: Dont re-throw the exception. its as simple as that.

Comment: Now , the code executes but, it doesn't wait for any key.

Comment: Add Console.Read(); before the return;

Answer (score 0):

You `Console.Read();` statement will never execute in your code.

Your program `return` or it will *thrown* an exception.

If you want it reachable, you can make a comment line in your catch block.

```
try
{
     throw new FormatException("Format");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     if (ex is FormatException || ex is OverflowException)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Caught Exception");
        Console.Read();
        return;
     }
     //throw;
 }
```

As an alternative, you can use [`finally`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) block even even if an exception occurs in the try block.

```
...
finally
{
    Console.Read(); // Will always execute
}
```

Comment: I already know that it is not executing. I want to make it reachable. and remove that warning.

Comment: It will still not execute due to the `return;`

Comment: Now , the code executes but, it doesn't wait for any key.

Comment: Actually, the code will not execute: You are throwing a `FormatException` and then catching a generic exception and checking for a `FormatException`, so the `if` block will execute and return. The compiler just cannot figure out that the code below it is still unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

well that's because it would through an exception in the try block straight away (throw new formatexception) and will never pass beyond that line.

Answer (score 0):

In your `try` block you throw an exception which means that the `catch` block will be executed. Your catch block either returns (in case the `if` is true) or it throws an exception (`throw` statement).

Either way, your function will never reach the code for which you are getting a warning.

What can you do to make it reachable? That is for you to figure out. From looking at your code, it is unclear what you actually want to achieve. As long as you don't share that with us, nobody can tell you what you need to change.

Answer (score 0):

My guess at what you wanted to do:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            throw new FormatException("Format");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex is FormatException || ex is OverflowException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Caught Exception");
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
```